# Laptop does not like external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my machine and got everything running about as it should, except for one thing: my external monitor can not be set as default.

Every time I plug in my external monitor, the screen extends how it's supposed to. However, when I attempt to set it as my default monitor, LightDM immediately goes into a loop where the screen goes off for about a second, and flashes on for a very brief interval.

Additionally, this problem happens if I end LightDM (`service` or other method) and re-launch it. I can enter my password, but then this same flashing happens.

However, this does not happen when I first boot up my machine.

How can I fix this issue?

---

Ubuntu 15.04, Intel HD 4400, NVIDIA GT745M (driver 352.14), Bumblebee

Running Cinnamon + Docky

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with Nvidia drivers and the solution was to have Launcher placement enabled on both monitors, else the situation was as your described. I guess it's bug of proprietary Nvidia drivers, because they don't see 2 monitors but one with resolution of both combined.